# Partitioning with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, partitioning

We have a requirement to delete data in the range of 200K from database everyday. Our application is Java/Java EE based using Oracle DB and Hibernate ORM tool.

We explored various options like

1. Hibernate batch processing
2. Stored procedure
3. Database partitioning

Our DBA suggests database partitioning is the best way to go, so we can easily recreate and drop the partitioned table everyday. Now the issue is we have 2 kinds of data, one which we want to delete everyday and the other which we want to keep it. Suppose this data is stored in table "Trade". Now with partitioning, we have 2 tables "Trade". We have already existing Hibernate based DAO layer to fetch/store trades from/to DB. When we decide to partition the database, how can we control the trades to go in which of the two tables through hibernate. Basically I want , the trades need to be deleted by end of the day, to go in partitioned table and the trades I want to keep, in main table. Please suggest how can this be possible with Hibernate. We may add an additional column to identify the trades to be deleted but how can we ensure these trades should go to partitioned trade table using hibernate.

I would appreciate if someone can suggest any better approach in case we are on wrong path.

Comment: May be you can create a Quartz job which runs every day and delete the records which can be deleted. I wouldn't do that on Oracle based mechanism.

Comment: We have a huge set of data and we need to delete this data in the range of 200K so through quartz job, first searching this range of data and then deleting would be very inefficient solution and secondly no reading from the database would be possible during the delete operation. So we decided to go for partition based approach.

Answer (score 1):

> When we decide to partition the database, how can we control the trades to go in which of the two tables through hibernate.

That's what [Hibernate Shards](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html) is for.

Comment: Is it still in developpment ? last time i looked at it, they were stuck on some really hard matters... (and last commit on sf.net was done on jan. 21st 2009)

Comment: @Thierry AFAIK, the project *is* in the Hibernate portfolio. Do you have any particular Jira issue in mind? What additional features are you missing that would require development?

Comment: Nop, i've just read the reference documentation to see what it could do. I've seen many limitations (for example 'shard' queries do not support distinct or sorting). The project having received no updates in more than one year, i was just wondering if it was still alive.

Comment: @Thierry Well, I guess it's a kind of virtuous circle (or vicious circle, as you want): more users, more needs, more activity, more features, more users, etc.

Comment: Ok so what is the message for users. I can see it is still in beta. Is it ready for production use? What is the time line for GA release?

Comment: @Alex You know, sometimes Beta are production grade software, this doesn't mean much (would you feel better if they rename the beta2 as GA?). My recommendation: check Hibernate Shards to see if it contains the features you need and test it. Personally, I think Shards is good enough for many use cases. Check [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=986999) for official feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hibernate inheritance strategy.

If you know at object creation that it will be deleted by the end of the day, you can create a VolatileTrade that is a subclass of Trade (with no other attribute). Use the 'table per concrete class' strategy ([section 9.1.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) of hibernate 3.3 reference documentation) for the mapping.

(I think i would do an abstract superclass Trade, and two concrete subclasses : PersistentTrade and VolatileTrade, so that if you have some other classes that you know will reference only PersistentTrade (or Volatile), you can constrain that in your code. If you had used the Trade superclass as the PersistentTrade, you won't be able to enforce that.)

The volatile trade will go in one table and the 'persitent' trade will go in another table.

Be aware that you won't be able to set a fk constraint on any Trade (persistent and volatile) from other table in the db.

Then you just have to clear the table when you want.

Be careful to define a locking mechanism so that no other thread will try to write data to the table during the drop and the create (if you use that). That won't be an easy task, and doing it rightfully might impact the performance of all operation inserting data in the table (as it will require acquiring the lock).

Wouldn't it be more easy to [truncate](http://psoug.org/reference/truncate.html) the table ?